# Open a new terminal tab in position "first" rather than "next" or "last"

Tags: gnome-terminal

The only available options in the terminal preferences for "New tab position" are "Next" and "Last". I would like to open new terminals as the first tab (reached by the `Alt+1` shortcut). Is there an easy way to achieve this behavior?

Screenshot of terminal general preferences window:
[image: Screenshot of terminal general preferences window]

Comment: The option is not there, so that would likely require a feature request with the developers of gnome-terminal.

Comment: The previous comment is correct, gnome-terminal doesn't support this feature. I have doubts if the upstream developer would accept this feature request, it's a very unnatural (to me) behavior that would have probably no other user than you. Or at least if they accept the request, I hope they also implement "previous" in addition to "first".

Comment: If you have a bit of C programming experience, you might try to implement this feature for yourself, based on the patch at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=709109. The variable "position" needs the value of 0. If you only do it for yourself, there's no need for another graphical entry in the settings dialog, just modify one (or both) existing cases to assign 0 rather than -1 or <current position>+1 as done currently. You'll easily find in the patch where a value is assigned to "position".

Comment: If you manage to compile and install a modified gnome-terminal, replacing the system one, you'll need to quit all gnome-terminal windows at once for the changes to take effect. If you mess up, fix it from a different terminal emulator (e.g. xterm). Disclaimer: Only do it if you have enough experience to fix if you happen to mess up, or if you're willing to take the risk; I won't be able to provide further support.

Comment: The aforementioned patch is not exactly what landed in the code, you should rather look at https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-terminal/-/commit/56cd640a2d7f861d537aa8dff65d12f312a1fb98.

Comment: Okay thanks for the info. @egmont the reason I want to do this, although I agree it's "unnatural" if you think about behavior in other applications (e.g. browser tabs). But in terminals I usually have a few "active work" tabs, and a few tabs running applications that I don't need to check often, and I like to navigate by ```Alt+<number>```, where Alt+1,2,3 etc are much easier to reach than tabs opened in the end. I'll see if I get around to implementing this myself, it's pretty easy to just use the shortcut to shift the tab's position to the left as well.